# How come I know that my execute statement is working fine?

Tags: mysql, groovy

I'm novice to Groovy and I have a doubt. Let's say I'm doing something like this :

```
db.execute '''
   //my sql commands
'''
```

Programmatically how can I find that my `execute` method succeeds?

I tried this way :

```
def status = db.execute '''
       //my sql commands
    '''
```

But even though the data have been inserted into the db ( which I have viewed in my mysql client ), the `status` returns `false`. Its confusing for me. Whats going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the [groovy.sql.Sql](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/sql/Sql.html#execute%28java.lang.String%29) object.  If you look at the API (linked previously) for the execute() method, it says it will return `false` for either a row count return value or a no results return value.

Since you mentioned an insert statement, check your row count via:

```
if (db.updateCount() > 0) { /* success! */ }
```